# Google Developer Console incorrectly believes my app is not designed for tablets

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, tablet

Here's the message I'm getting in the Developer console:

> **Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:**
>
> Your APK should include customised drawable assets for common tablet screen densities.

-In my manifest I have:

```
<supports-screens
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

-In **/src/main/res** I have **mipmap-hdpi** to **xxxhdpi** folders each containing a launcher icon.

-I have uploaded the appropriate tablet screenshots as the store demands.

All of the above seems to work fine. So, what am I missing?

From what I can gather by searching, it's possible that a lack of drawable content is incorrectly failing my APK, but I have no need for any other than the launcher icons. Would anybody be able to tell me how to dummy this, please? I can't even find an explicit description of the folder structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I gave up and filled out this form to declare the app tablet-friendly, if you're sure all the right boxes are ticked, for a manual review. The app was approved within a day and a few days later the "Designed for phones" label on the Google Play Store was gone. No explanation was given regarding the problem.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/tabletq

Comment: Interesting... I've got 2 apps, both made with Ionic and I'm getting this issue on one of them totally randomly

Answer (score 1):

I've had that issue before, look here https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html
You will need to add new layouts for larger screen along with the different drawable like:

```
      res/layout-large/main.xml for tablets:
```

Instead of just using

```
      res/layout/main.xml for handsets:
```

Comment: <supports-screens> Lets you specify the screen sizes your application supports and enable screen compatibility mode for screens larger than what your application supports. It's important that you always use this element in your application to specify the screen sizes your application supports.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned <supports-screens> in my question. I cloned /res/layout/activity_main.xml to /res/layout-large/main.xml but it didn't help, I'm still being told to use different assets for tablets. The app is a full-screen webapp, it adapts automatically. There's nothing else obvious in the link you provided that I'm missing. You can ask for a manual review regarding tablet detection (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/tabletq) so I'll try that and see what happens, I don't understand why it's telling me there's a problem but not what the problem is.

Comment: */res/layout/activity_main.xml to /res/layout-large/activity_main.xml

Comment: You need both file not just one large but the normal layout file as well.

Comment: I have both, it's the same file in two folders. I've filled out the form already, see what they say.

Comment: The manual tablet-friendly review form returned an approval so I've posted it as the solution for clarity. The email response may have been automated, it didn't address my request for an explanation, so it seems the specific problem must remain a mystery. Thanks anyway!